# PHP Query to UPDATE/DELETE a dynamically generated input field in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table where user can create row with adding input fields dynamically (combination with jquery). I'm successfully able to insert it into the mysql database.

If users want to edit the added already existing fields, I have an edit page where the values are fetched from the mysql DB and populated again into the dynamically creatable table.[image]

Now there are the below probabilities:-

1. User only makes minor changes on the existing values. In that case
   the table has to be UPDATED with the changed values
2. User Deletes one/multiple row(randomly selected and as per users wish). So when form submitted the php query should only DELETE that perticular row/s in the DB.
3. User ADDS another row to the previous existing row values, in that case the php query should UPDATE the previous values and INSERT the newly added row values.
4. The above sequence is not necessarilly restricted the same order. User can perform all the above three function simultaneously at the same time.

Now my problem is(only for the backend) I'm finding a hard time to frame a php & sql query so as to update to the mysql.

my php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $number1 = count($_POST['item']); //
    for($i=0; $i<$number1; $i++){
       $item = strip_tags(trim($_POST['item'][$i]));
       $description = strip_tags(trim($_POST['description'][$i]));
       $unitcost = strip_tags(trim($_POST['unitcost'][$i]));
       $qty = strip_tags(trim($_POST['qty'][$i])); // Quantity
       $sno = strip_tags(trim($_POST['sno'][$i]));// serial number

       //QUERY1 if minor updates to above variable then UPDATE (eg, qty value is changed from 3 to 4)
       //QUERY2 if row is deleted then DELETE that particular row from db (eg, sno 3 deleted from the table should DELETE corresponding mysql DB values also)
       //QUERY3 if row is added then that particular row values should be INSERT (eg, sno 4 is added which is not in the mysql db. So this has to be INSERTED.)
       }
     }
```

Pardon me to have asked such question. I'm wasting a whole lot of time with the above queries unable to execute properly. I only require an idea not necessarily the whole code.

Hope all of you out there would advice me some ideas on how this could be implemented. Thanks for the help in advance. Expecting a positive reply.

**NB: Just to remind you again, The front end is a Dynamically ADD/DELETE Input Field table**

Comment: i think, having a unique id for each row will help, as long as the id is present during the execution of your above probabilities, for instance probability 2, sending the row id through jquery to the backend then selecting all values that match the id and deleting them all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the reply, appreciate @ckrudelux and @codefather for their intention to help me.
Although their advise didn't help me to structure my query. So I had a long workaround and found out below solution. I'm posting the solution because I couldn't find any article online when it comes to UPDATE/DELETE a dynamically generated input table.

Hope this would be of help to someone.

So what I did basically is that I took all the values into array.

In my dynamically generated add input table code, I added an `<input type="hidden" name="sno[]" value="newrow">`. So this will be clubbed with the form post. I'm using the normal html post and not ajax.

now my submit.php has ben changed to below

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $productid = $_POST['productd'];// No striptag functions 
                                     // due to illustration purpose

     // First of all, we need to fetch the querying db table. 
     // This is required in order to compare the existing row values 
     // with the posted values
     $fetchproduct  = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productid=?");
     $fetchproduct  ->bind_param('s',$productid);
     $fetchproduct  ->execute();
     $fetchresult   = $fetchproduct ->get_result();

     $serialnumber=array(); // Assigning array to fetch the primary key: Serial Number
     while($row = $fetchresult->fetch_assoc()){
        $serialnumber[]         = $row["sno"];
     }

     //Newly Inserted Values

     //$_POST['sno'] is taken from the dynamic input field defined earlier in this post. 
     //Basically what we are doing here is we are comparing (the values 
     //which have been posted from the primary page) and (values present in the db table). 
     //The difference will give an array of newly inserted table input field values

     $insert = array_diff($_POST['sno'],$serialnumber); 


     //Deleted Values

     // This will Difference those values in the db table and values which are 
     // deleted from the primary dynamic table page
     $delete = array_diff($serialnumber,$_POST['sno']); 
     $countdelete = count($delete);  // Counting how many values have been
                                     // lined up for deleting   

     //Updated Values

      // array_intersect will give us the common values present in both the array.
      // This means that there is no deletion or insertion to the dynamic table fields.
      $intersect = array_intersect($serialnumber, $_POST['sno']);
      $update = array_values($intersect);
      $countupdate = count($update);

     //INSERT ADDED VALUES TO DB
     foreach($insert as $key=>$ivalue){
        // ID       
        if(isset($_POST['id'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['id'][$key])) {
            $id = strip_tags(trim($_POST['id'][$key]));
        }
        // ITEM
        if(isset($_POST['item'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['item'][$key])) {
            $item = strip_tags(trim($_POST['item'][$key]));
        }
        // DESCRIPTION
        if(isset($_POST['description'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['description'][$key])) {
            $description = strip_tags(trim($_POST['description'][$key]));
        }
        // UNITCOST
        if(isset($_POST['unitcost'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['unitcost'][$key])) {
            $unitcost = strip_tags(trim($_POST['unitcost'][$key]));
        }
        // QUANTITY
        if(isset($_POST['qty'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['qty'][$key])) {
            $qty = strip_tags(trim($_POST['qty'][$key]));
        }
        // AMOUNT
        if(isset($_POST['amount'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['amount'][$key])) {
            $amount = strip_tags(trim($_POST['amount'][$key]));
        }

        // INSERT INTO THE DATABASE
        $inserttable = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO product (productid, item, description, unitcost, qty, amount) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $inserttable->bind_param('ssssss', $id, $item, $description, $unitcost, $qty, $amount);
        $inserttable->execute();
        if($inserttable){
            header( 'Location:to/your/redirect page.php' ) ; // NOT MANDADTORY, You can put whatever you want
            $_SESSION['updatemsg'] = "Success";
        }
     }  

     //UPDATE EXISTING VALUES TO DB
     for($j=0; $j<$countupdate; $j++){
        // ID       
        if(isset($_POST['id'][$j]) && !empty($_POST['id'][$j])) {
            $uid = strip_tags(trim($_POST['id'][$j]));
        }
        // ITEM
        if(isset($_POST['item'][$j]) && !empty($_POST['item'][$j])) {
            $uitem = strip_tags(trim($_POST['item'][$j]));
        }
        // DESCRIPTION
        if(isset($_POST['description'][$j]) && !empty($_POST['description'][$j])) {
            $udescription = strip_tags(trim($_POST['description'][$j]));
        }
        // UNITCOST
        if(isset($_POST['unitcost'][$j]) && !empty($_POST['unitcost'][$j])) {
            $uunitcost = strip_tags(trim($_POST['unitcost'][$j]));
        }
        // QUANTITY
        if(isset($_POST['qty'][$j]) && !empty($_POST['qty'][$j])) {
            $uqty = strip_tags(trim($_POST['qty'][$j]));
        }
        // AMOUNT
        if(isset($_POST['amount'][$j]) && !empty($_POST['amount'][$j])) {
            $uamount = strip_tags(trim($_POST['amount'][$j]));
        }

        // UPDATE THE DATABASE      
        $updatetable = $link->prepare("UPDATE product SET item=?, description=?, unitcost=?, qty=?, amount=? WHERE sno=?");
        $updatetable->bind_param('ssssss', $uitem, $udescription, $uunitcost, $uqty, $uamount, $update[$j]);
        $updatetable->execute(); 
        if($updatetable){
            $_SESSION['updatemsg'] = "Success";
        }
      }

      //DELETE VALUES FROM DB
      foreach($delete as $sno){
      $deletetable = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM product WHERE sno=?");
      $deletetable->bind_param('s', $sno);
      $deletetable->execute();
      if($deletetable){
        $_SESSION['updatemsg'] = "Success";
      }
    }
   }else {
       $_SESSION['updatemsg'] = "Error";
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a frontend problem. You need to define how you tell the backend whats happening.

```
<input name="items[$i][name]" />
```

This will show up as nice array to loop through in php.

```
foreach($_POST[items] AS $item){
    if( $item['delete'] ){
        //delete code
    }
}else{
    //Insert/Update
}
```

If you want to delete something simply make the field hidden and add a flag to it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[$i][delete]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[$i][id]" />
```